# Questions about a la carte data types

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming

I was reading [the original paper about data types a la carte](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~W.Swierstra/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf) and decided to try to implement the idea in Scala (I know it's already implemented in many functional libraries). Unfortunately I found the original paper is hard to comprehend and I stuck somewhere in the beginning. Then I found [another paper](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/alacarte.pdf) that was easier to understand and I managed to rewrite Haskell code from the paper into Scala, you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/dmgcodevil/ddc3d3fa13f70d15db9f13cf383bfc04). However I still struggling to understand a few moments:

1. A quote from the second paper

Orignal `Expr` data type

```
data Expr = Val Int | Add Expr Expr
```

New type signature:

```
data Arith e = Val Int | Add e e
```

> For any functor `f`, its induced recursive datatype, `Fix f`, is defined as the least fixpoint of `f`, implemented as follows:

```
data Fix f = In (f (Fix f))
```

> Now that we have tied the *recursive knot* of a signature,
>   `Fix Arith` is a language equivalent to the original `Expr` datatype
>   which allowed integer values and addition.

What does it mean exactly "we have tied the recursive knot of a signature"  and what does it mean `Fix Arith` is a language equivalent to the original `Expr` ?

The actual type of `In` is `In :: f (Fix f) -> Fix f`
If we try to construct a value using `In` construct and `Val 1` variable we'll get the following result:

```
> :t  In(Val 1)
> In(Val 1) :: Fix Arith
```

Scala encoding of the same data types:

```scala
  sealed trait Arith[A]
  case class Val[A](x: Int) extends Arith[A]
  case class Add[A](a: A, b: A) extends Arith[A]

  trait Fix[F[_]]
  case class In[F[_]](exp: F[Fix[F]]) extends Fix[F]
```

2. `fold` function
   The `fold` function has the following signature and implementation

Haskell:

```
fold :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
fold f (In t) = f (fmap (fold f) t)
```

Scala variant I came up with

```
  def fold[F[_] : Functor, A](f: F[A] => A): Fix[F] => A = {
    case In(t) =>
      val g: F[Fix[F]] => F[A] = implicitly[Functor[F]].lift(fold(f))
      f(g(t))
  }
```

The thing that I'm curious about is that in my Scala version function `g` has the following type `F[Fix[F]] => F[A]` but the type of variable `t` after pattern matching is `LaCarte$Add` with value `Add(In(Val(1)),In(Val(2)))`, how it happens that it's valid to apply function `g` to `LaCarte$Add` ? Also, I'd very appreciate if you can help me to understand `fold` function ?

Quote from the paper:

> The first argument of fold is an *f-algebra*, which provides
>   the behavior of each constructor associated with a given signature `f`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does it mean exactly “we have tied the ‘recursive knot’ of a signature”?

The original `Expr` datatype is recursive, referring to itself in its own definition:

```
data Expr = Val Int | Add Expr Expr
```

The `Arith` type “factors out” the recursion by replacing recursive calls with a parameter:

```
data Arith e = Val Int | Add e e
```

The original `Expr` type can have any depth of nesting, which we want to support with `Arith` as well, but the maximum depth depends on what type we choose for `e`:

- `Arith Void` can’t be nested: it can only be a literal value (`Val n`) because we can’t construct an `Add`, because we can’t obtain a value of type `Void` (it has no constructors)
- `Arith (Arith Void)` can have one level of nesting: the outer constructor can be an `Add`, but the inner constructors can only be `Lit`.
- `Arith (Arith (Arith Void))` can have two levels
- And so on

What `Fix Arith` gives us is a way to talk about the *fixed point* `Arith (Arith (Arith …))` with no limit on the depth.

This is just like how we can replace a recursive function with a non-recursive function and recover the recursion with the fixed-point combinator:

```hs
factorial' :: (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer
factorial' recur n = if n <= 1 then 1 else n * recur (n - 1)

factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial = fix factorial'

factorial 5 == 120
```

> What does it mean `Fix Arith` is a language equivalent to the original `Expr`?

The language (grammar) that `Fix Arith` represents is equivalent to the language that `Expr` represents; that is, they’re isomorphic: you can write a pair of total functions `Fix Arith -> Expr` and `Expr -> Fix Arith`.

> How it happens that it’s valid to apply function `g` to `LaCarte$Add`?

I’m not very familiar with Scala, but it looks like `Add` is a subtype of `Arith`, so the parameter of `g` of type `F[Fix[F]]` can be filled with a value of type `Arith[Fix[Arith]]` which you get by matching on the `In` constructor to “unfold” one level of recursion.